# What is the control flow of Hadoop mapper with MultipleInputs?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Objective: To implement `Reduce Side Join`

I have Job Chaining (two jobs) at present in my code. now I want to implement joining at the reduce-side with another job. And I have to take multiple inputs:

`Input #1:` Output from the previous reducer.
`Input #2:` New file from HDFS to implement join.

Saw some articles on how to use `MultipleInputs.addInputhPath(job, Path, InputFormat.class, Mapper.class);`

So I understand that I have to use it twice, once for `Input #1` and once for `Input #2`.

`Question 1:` Then if I use two separate mappers and a single reducer, which mapper will be executed first (or will they be executed in parallel)? How to check on the reducer side which mapper has emitted the `<key, value>` pair?

`Question 2:` If I use a single mapper and a single reducer, what will be the control flow?

`Question 3:` More of a Hack, i.e. not using MultipleInputs

Is it OK (performance wise) to use `DistributedCache` to load the `Input #2` in the reducer's `setup()` method? And taking the output from the previous reducer as the only Input for the job.

`Note:` The `Input #2` file is pretty small in size.

Comment: If your Input#2 is small you can go with DistributedCache

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**
`Map` tasks for both the Mappers should run parallel provided slots are available. Presence of a single slot may cause them to run in sequence(with possible interleaving), but it's not a normal scenario. If there is some configuration for Mapper sequence I'm not aware of this.

Again I doubt that any `api` is available to identify which Mapper emitted `<key, value>`. To be precise, just the identification of `value` is required since same `key` may be emitted by different Maps. This is usually achieved by adding a prefix tag to the output value and resolving those tags in the reducer. eg :

```
if(value.toString.startsWith("Input#1")){  //processing code }
```

Have a look at this [blogpost](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.in/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html), it has all the required tips and tricks. Please note that all those examples are using old `mapred` api. But the logic will be the same in any case.

**Answer 2:**
 Without `MultipleInputs`, in the `Map` you have to identify the filename of an incoming  pair using the available `Context` object. eg :

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();   
        //............
}
```

Then just prepend a suitable tag to output value and rest is same as answer1.

**Answer 3:**
This is tricky. Use of `DistributedCache` for joining boosts performance when the file that's going to be added to the cache is small. This is probably due to the fact that the job now runs with a lesser number of `Map` tasks. But it affects adversely with the large files. The dilemma is to know how many bytes are considered small for `DistributedCache`.

Since you mentioned that Input #2 file is pretty small, this should be your most suited solution.

NB : Many comments of this post are (a little) opinion based. Expecting inputs from experts.